# GWT compilation failed (not emitting code for accessing method) (LibGdx,Box2D,Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, compilation, box2d

i am working on a little LibGdx Box2D Game with Java in Eclipse. So i want to compile the project for my Website with GWT Compiler. It starts the compiling but then it stops and say "GWT compilation failed". Also it shows this error log :

http://private.bgegames.de/docs/java/error-log.txt

I couldtn compile the desktop version to a runnable jar file, so i created a MANIFEST.MF and Cleaned the project and removed a DesktopLauncher of another project from [Properties -> Run/Debug Settings. There were two of then 1. from the project and one from another. Then it worked perfectly and i tried the same at the HTML project but it doesnt worked.
Please Help ME !! Thank you ! :)

Kind Regards,
Jona

EDIT : If a compile a new project the same errors are appearing, but the GWT Compiler dont care and compiles successfully to the end.